# yunet.onnx reading issue in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

i would like to detect  faces with mask, here is one example of image :
[image]

classical side face detector

```
faceCascade =cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_profileface.xml")
```

does not detect  faces  well, therefore i  tried to search  a little more and found following documentation :
[yunet  documentation](https://medium.com/@silkworm/yunet-ultra-high-performance-face-detection-in-opencv-a-good-solution-for-real-time-poc-b01063e251d5)

i have tried to implement  this model in my code  :

```
import  numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import math
#faceCascade =cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
#faceCascade =cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_profileface.xml")
frame =cv2.imread("distance_Measure.jpg")
frame =cv2.resize(frame,(500,500))
gray =cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
face_detector = cv2.FaceDetectorYN_create("yunet.onnx", "", (0, 0))
#faces =faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray,scaleFactor=1.1,minNeighbors=5,minSize=(20,20))
_, faces = face_detector.detect(gray)
l =[]
lf =[]
i =1
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    s =str(i)
    cv2.putText(frame,s,(x,y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)
    i+=1
    l =[]
    l.append(x)
    l.append(y)
    lf.append(l)
    print(l)
print(lf)
close_person =""
for i in range(len(lf)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(lf)):
        d =math.sqrt((lf[j][1]-lf[i][1])**2+((lf[j][0]-lf[i][0])**2))
        print("P",i+1,"-P",j+1,"=",d)
        if d <150:
            close_person ="Person " +str(i+1)+" and Person "+str(j+1)+";"
            cv2.line(frame,(lf[i][0],lf[i][1]),(lf[j][0],lf[j][1]),(0,0,255),2)
    close_person+=" are not following social distance"
    print(close_person)
cv2.imshow("Displayed_Persons",frame)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
plt.show()
```

but it returns  following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\AI_Project\Social_Distance_Measurement_Example.py", line 10, in <module>
    face_detector = cv2.FaceDetectorYN_create("yunet.onnx", "", (0, 0))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\onnx\onnx_importer.cpp:194: error: (-5:Bad argument) Can't read ONNX file: yunet.onnx in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20211220::ONNXImporter::ONNXImporter'
```

i have searched again  and found following documentation :
[searched solution](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/8439)

but  i could not  clarify  how to solve given problem, please help me